# ¿Cómo puedo identificar el índice dónde se repite consecutivamente una condición con map_dbl?

Tags: r, funciones, tibble

Tengo una lista de 106 tibbles y quiero obtener de cada uno de esos tibbles un índice que cumpla por tercera vez vonsecutiva una condición, sin embargo obtengo el índice en cada tibble dónde se cumple la condición por tercera vez en total.

`idx8 = data_sensor %>% map_dbl(~min(which(cumsum(.x[["Temperature"]] < 8.0) == 3)))`

Con el siguiente código, he logrado identificar aquellos índices que cumplen el requisito, teniendo en cuenta que en mi tibble, el primer valor siempre está por debajo de 8.0. Para todos los demás casos no funciona.

```
idx8 = data_sensor %>% map_dbl(~min(which(cumsum(.x[["Temperature"]] < 8.0) == 3)))

idx84 = data_sensor %>%  map_dbl(~min(which(cumsum(.x[["Temperature"]] < 8.0) == 4)))

idx83 = idx84-idx8
```

Para todo id83 = 1 se habrá cumplido la condición

```
>  idx83
  [1]   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
 [23]   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN   1   1   1   1   1 NaN   1   1   1   1   1   1
 [45]   1   1  12 NaN   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
 [67]   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN   1   1   1   4   3   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN
 [89]   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN   1   1 Inf   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

¿Cómo puedo encontrar el índice para cuando se cumple la condición por tercera vez seguida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un posible modo de solucionar el problema ha sido mediante el siguiente código y función:

idx8 és el identificador que contiene:

```
idx84 = data_sensor %>% 
  map_dbl(~min(which(cumsum(.x[["Temperature"]] < 8.0) == 4)))
idx87 = data_sensor %>% 
  map_dbl(~min(which(cumsum(.x[["Temperature"]] < 8.0) == 7)))
idx8=idx87-idx84
```

A lo largo de dicho identificador n sumará +1 para aquellos valores que se cumpla la condición para que aparezcan 3 valores consecutivos con temperatura mayor a 8.0.

También tenemos en cuenta que no contenga na's y guardamos en el vector idx_pos8[] la posición en la que se cumple el requisito.

```
  for (i in seq_along(idx8)){ 
      if ((idx8[i] == 3)&(!is.na(idx8[i])){
        n=n+1
        idx_pos8[i]=idx87[i]
      } else if ((is.na(idx8[i])||(idx8[i] != 3)){
          idx_pos8[i]=0
    }}
```

En el caso que no sean valores consecutivos durante tres veces o contenga valores na, idx_pos8[]=0.